# Creating arrays of objects of different derived classes using txt file reading. How to do better?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class. From which many other classes are inherited that need to be added to the file.
Then it is necessary to do the exact opposite, that is, the result will be an array of objects of different objects of derived classes.
What would be the best way to do this? Because my implementation seems to me the worst option.

In a text file, it looks like this:

```
 Student JohnCamper
{<<FirstName>> : <<John>>,
<<LastName>> : <<Camper>>,
<<StudentID>> : <<45213>>,
<<Place Of Residence>> : <<94-932>>,
<<Sex>> : <<Male>>}
TaxiDriver ArnoldTrump
{<<FirstName>> : <<Arnold>>,
<<LastName>> : <<Trump>>}
```

Code:

```
public abstract class People
   {
    private Attribute<string>[] _attributes = new Attribute<string>[2];

    protected People(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        var firstname = new Attribute<string>(firstName, "FirstName");
        var lastname = new Attribute<string>(lastName, "LastName");
        _attributes[0] = firstname;
        _attributes[1] = lastname;
    }

    public virtual void Teach()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("teaching someone");
    }

    public virtual void Study()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{engaged in self-education");
    }

    public virtual void Drive()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{is driving");
    }

    public string[] GetAttributesNames()
    {
        var result = new string[_attributes.Length];
        for (var index = 0; index < result.Length; index++)
        {
            result[index] = _attributes[index].GetName();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public string[] GetAttributesData()
    {
        var result = new string[_attributes.Length];
        for (int index = 0; index < result.Length; index++)
        {
            result[index] = _attributes[index].GetData();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void Copy()
    {
        var temp = new Attribute<string>[_attributes.Length + 1];
        for (var index = 0; index < _attributes.Length; index++)
        {
            temp[index] = _attributes[index];
        }

        _attributes = temp;
    }

    protected void AddAttribute(Attribute<string> attribute)
    {
        Copy();
        var index = _attributes.Length - 1;
        _attributes[index] = attribute;
    }
}
public People[] ReadFile()
    {
        People[] result;
        var sizePattern = new Regex(@".*\s{(.|\n)*?}");
        var linePattern = new Regex(@"<<.*>>\s:\s<<(.*)>>");
        var objTypePattern = new Regex(@"(.*)\s(.*){");
        using (var sr = _file.OpenText())
        {
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var matches = sizePattern.Matches(text);
            result = new People[CalcSize(text)];
            for (var index = 0; index < matches.Count; index++)
            {
                result[index] = ObjectCreate(matches[index]);
            }
        }

        return result;

        int CalcSize(string text)
        {
            var count = 0;
            foreach (Match match in sizePattern.Matches(text))
            {
                count++;
            }

            return count;
        }

        People ObjectCreate(Match match)
        {
            People people = null;
            var groups = match.Groups;
            var objType = match.Value.Split(" ")[0];
            var attributes = GetAttributes(match);
            if (objType == "Student")
            {
                people = new Student(attributes[0],attributes[1],attributes[2],attributes[3],attributes[4]);
            }
            else if (objType == "TaxiDriver")
            {
                people = new TaxiDriver(attributes[0],attributes[1]);
            }

            return people;
        }

        string[] GetAttributes(Match match)
        {
            var text = match.Value;
            var matches = linePattern.Matches(text);
            var size = matches.Count;
            var attributes = new string[size];
            for (var index = 0; index < size; index++)
            {
                var group = matches[index].Groups;
                var temp = group[1].Value;
                attributes[index] = temp;

            }

            return attributes;
        }
    }
public class Student : People
{
    public Student(string firstName, string lastName, string studentId,string stPlaceOfResidence, string studentSex) : base(firstName, lastName)
    {
        var id = new Attribute<string>(studentId, "StudentID");
        var sex = new Attribute<string>(studentSex,"Sex");
        var placeOfResidence = new Attribute<string>(stPlaceOfResidence, "Place Of Residence");
        AddAttribute(id);
        AddAttribute(placeOfResidence);
        AddAttribute(sex);
    }

    public override void Study()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student is studying");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show an actual concrete example of the text file content without those `<<...>>` placeholders (insert the example as text to your question, no other screenshot, please). The format looks kinda like Json, but i am not sure due some confusing ambiguity introduced by those placeholders...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to serialize/deserialize data objects. Since your text file looks kinda like Json, i would suggest you familiarize yourself with a Json serializer such as _Json.NET_, which makes it very easy to serialize (write) data objects into a json text file, as well as making it easy to deserializing (reading) such a json text file back into actual data objects...)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56417549/edit) your question to include the data. [Do not post screenshots](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Do not attempt to post code in comments.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I corrected the question.